# When do routed units capture a castle/stronghold

Tags: game-of-thrones

If some units rout and are able to retreat in to a territory that has an unoccupied castle or stronghold, does that castle count as captured immediately? Or do you need to wait until the next turn when the routed units are able to 'stand up' again?

The reason I ask is that on the final turn (i.e. no chance for routed units to stand), this ruling can have an effect on the number of castles and hence, who wins the game

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, even routed units immediately control the areas they occupy.**

According to the [FFG rule book](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/agot-bg-2nd-ed/support/VA65_AGoT2_Rulebook_web.pdf),

> **Controlling Areas** - A House is said to control a land area when it has at least one Footman, Knight, or Siege Engine in the area, or has previously established control in that area by placing a Power token there (see below).

Comment: "Immediately" is important because user link64 specifically asked about this. If the retreating units control a territory that causes its player to achieve victory, the game ends as soon as the retreating is complete. There is no waiting for the next turn.

Comment: you're right. I agree.